# Xamarin forms SQLite relation

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am going to create an app in Xamarin forms and starting with SQLite. I need to have unique list items for each Main item in the app.

For example, I am having a list with items. When I am selecting an item in the list a new page will pop up and display the items of that item.

So from my point of view I am in need of two SQLite tables with relations between.

**This is the Main table with all profiles**

```
[Table("Profiles")]
public class ProfileItems
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }
    public string ProfileRace { get; set; }
    public string iconn = "icon.png";
    public string ProfileIcon { get; set; }
    public DateTime BDay { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<LoggItems> Loggs { get; set; }

}
```

**This is the logg table for each Profile, which should be unique for each profile**

```
[Table("Loggs")]
public class LoggItems
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(ProfileItems))]
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
}
```

**Adding the items like this**

```
public class ProfileDatabase
{

    readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

    public ProfileDatabase(string dbPath)
    {
        database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        database.CreateTableAsync<ProfileItems>().Wait();
        database.CreateTableAsync<LoggItems>().Wait();
    }
    

    //Profile
    public Task<List<ProfileItems>> GetProfileAsync()
    {
        return database.Table<ProfileItems>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public Task<ProfileItems> GetProfileAsync(int id)
    {
        return database.Table<ProfileItems>().Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public Task<int> SaveProfileAsync(ProfileItems profileItems)
    {
        if (profileItems.Id != 0)
        {
            return database.UpdateAsync(profileItems);
        }
        else
        {
            return database.InsertAsync(profileItems);
        }
    }

    public  Task<int> DeleteProfileAsync(ProfileItems profileItems)
    {
        return database.DeleteAsync(profileItems);
    }


    //Logg
    public Task<List<LoggItems>> GetLoggAsync()
    {
        return database.Table<LoggItems>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public Task<LoggItems> GetLoggAsync(int id)
    {
        return database.Table<LoggItems>().Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public Task<int> SaveLoggAsync(LoggItems loggItems)
    {
        if (loggItems.Id != 0)
        {
            return database.UpdateAsync(loggItems);
        }
        else
        {
            return database.InsertAsync(loggItems);
        }
    }

    public Task<int> DeleteLoggAsync(LoggItems loggItems)
    {
        return database.DeleteAsync(loggItems);
    }
}
```

Both Logg and Profile list/tables do work but they do not have any relations between so the loggs show the same in all profile.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about to use Linq and join the relationships. 
**1.-** First you have to add the namespace:

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

**2.-** Change the property in the class ProfileItems to be a ***IEnumerable***

```cs
[OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
public virtual IEnumerable<LoggItems> Loggs { get; set; }
```

**3.-** This is the method to join the loggs with the profile items.

```cs
var profiles = await GetProfileAsync();
var loggs = await GetLoggAsync();
var query = from p in profiles
    join l in loggs on p.Id equals l.ProfileId into list
    select new ProfileItems
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        ProfileIcon = p.ProfileIcon,
        ProfileName = p.ProfileName,
        ProfileRace = p.ProfileRace,
        BDay = p.BDay,
        Loggs = list
    };
```

Comment: Try now. I have added the whole solution https://github.com/merlieon/Doggalogg

I tried your GetProfileInclude() but getting error that I cannot use Include in async method.

Comment: Also getting error on InverseProperty. 
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'InverseProperty' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) DoggaLogg.Android, DoggaLogg.iOS, DoggaLogg.UWP C:\Users\mawil3\source\repos\DoggaLogg\DoggaLogg\DoggaLogg\Model\LoggItems.cs 27 Active

Comment: I can't compile your solution, I don't know but it's missing something. We can try to use linq with joins and obtain all the properties you need, remove the inverse property I'll write an example.

Comment: I am sorry but where should I use the method?

Comment: I published on your repo, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add "*virtual"* keyword for enabling lazy loading.

```cs
[OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
public virtual List<LoggItems> Loggs { get; set; }
```

And there's the "*[InverseProperty]*" to specify their related navigation property.

```cs
public class LoggItems
{
     *
     [ForeignKey(typeof(ProfileItems))]
     [InverseProperty("Loggs")]
     public int ProfileId { get; set; }
     *
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. There are some thing I do not really understand. First, How do I add the [InverserProperty], is it built in the SQLite or is it a nuget?

Second. I do not really know if I am adding the items correctly. Shouldn't I add the loggs into the Loggs list? (public virtual List<LoggItems> Loggs { get; set; }), Now the loggs is just adding as a new Logg Item. Will that work?

third. How can I call the child of each profile item. Right now I am only binding to the items in the LoggItem class which will only generate a new parent, if I understand this correct.

Comment: 1.- The [InverseProperty] it's a data annotation for sqlite to denotate the navigation property. Here's some help [Link](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/inverseproperty-attribute)

2.- The items you have are correctly, I recommend calling the columns id as the name of your table like _ProfileItemsId_ or _LoggItemsId_

3.- When you relate the tables the properties you can call them as follows:
`var list = database.ProfileItems.ToList();`
in that list you will have all the properties and their children as you marked in the class.

Comment: Do you have a repo that you can share with us?

Comment: I can't compile, you must add the repo to the main folder where the .sln is located

Comment: I found this one GetAllWithChildrenAsync(), Trying to figure out how it works. maybe you have used it before?

Comment: I don't have used it before, but you can try, tell me if it works maybe it's a better way.