# Xamarin.forms retrieve firebase data according to date

Tags: xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my xamarin.forms app I am using firebase database for storing users information.I am trying to fetch data between certain date range.

**My data model**

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string EmailID { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
        public List<UserLocationData> userdata { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class UserLocationData
    {
        public string Latitude { get; set; }
        public string Longitude { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    }
```

From my I app I will send two dates (Start Date and End date) so that I would like to get the data which have `DateTime` parameter inside this range. How to write the query for that?

**What I have tried**

In my Firebase helper class,

```
 public async Task<List<Person>> GetPersonLocation(int personId,DateTime startDate,DateTime endDate)
    {       
        return (await firebase
          .Child("Persons")       
          .OrderBy("DateTime")
          .StartAt(startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt"))
          .EndAt(endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt"))
          .OnceAsync<Person>()).Select(item => new Person
          {
              Name = item.Object.Name,
              PersonId = item.Object.PersonId,
              PhoneNumber = item.Object.PhoneNumber,
              EmailID = item.Object.EmailID,
              Address = item.Object.Address,
              Password = item.Object.Password,
              IsAdmin = item.Object.IsAdmin,
              Status = item.Object.Status,
              userdata=item.Object.userdata

          }).ToList();

    }
```

I am getting exception like this :

```
Response: {
  "error" : "Index not defined, add \".indexOn\": \"DateTime\", for path \"/Persons\", to the rules"
}
```

Which is not seems right.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you want to use **One to Many** relation in sqlite, and query data between two data, am I riht?

If yes, I suggest you can modify your data model, because your two model don't have any relations.

```
public  class person
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations  = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<UserLocationData> userdata { get; set; }
}

public class UserLocationData
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }    
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(typeof(person))]
    public int personid { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can query the data between two date like this:

```
var persons = await sqliteconn.Table<person>().ToListAsync();
        var locations = await sqliteconn.Table<UserLocationData>().ToListAsync();

        var query = from p in persons
                    join location in locations on p.Id equals location.personid
                    into list1
                    select new person
                    {
                        Id = p.Id,
                        Name = p.Name,
                        userdata = list1.Where(s => s.DateTime >= Convert.ToDateTime("2019-02-01") && s.DateTime <= Convert.ToDateTime("2019-03-01"))
                    };           

        var list = query.ToList();
```

There are same thread that you can take a look:

[Xamarin forms SQLite relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802032/xamarin-forms-sqlite-relation)

**Update:**

You can try to get all data from Persons Table for firebase, then see if there are some data in userdata, if yes, now you can filter data

Comment: HI Thanks for the reply. I am using firebase data base

Comment: What changes should I do for that?

Comment: Bro can you help me?

Comment: @Anand You can try to  get all data from Persons Table for firebase, then see if there are some data in userdata, if yes, now you can filter data.

Comment: Yes bro. I tried like that. It is the best way. Thanks

Comment: @Anand If you solve your problem, please remember to mark the helpful reply as answer, or you can also post new reply and mark it as answer, it is beneficial to others to find this answer, thanks.

Comment: Bro, Can you edit your answer and mention the suggestion provided by you? I can accept that